# Selenium navigating with back even though no such command is in code

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not sure what or how selenium is doing this but when I first started to run this code it was performing more or less as expected.  The only real issue was it would sometimes not click to go to a link and sometimes it would.  However, it would always close the current page and then open another page as this was the only work around I could find to not run into stale element reference (ie: just trying to click a link, going to link, then going back was not working).

However, now all of a sudden selenium is doing some very strange things.  It completely ignores the go = False statement and somehow goes back to the search results page selects the next link in the list and clicks (even though before when I tried this I would get stale reference error).  I believe it started doing this after I was able to completely get through the list of sites and list of phones once.  Then it just started ignoring and going back.

```
class Searcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.phones = ["Google Pixel 3", "Google Pixel 4"]
        self.search_sites = ["The Verge", "android central", "MacRumors"]
        self.text_finder = {"The Verge": ["div", {"class" : "c-comments__cbody"}], "Android Central":["div", {"class": "comment__content"}], "MacRumors": ["div", {"class": "bbWrapper"}]}
        self.timestamp_finder = {"The Verge": ["a", {"data-ui" : "timestamp"}], "Android Central": ["footer"], "MacRumors": ["time", {"class": "u-dt"}]}

    def searching_site(self, site):
        for i in site:
            return site[i]
    def searching_phones(self, phone):
        for i in phone:
            return phone[i]
    def text_finding(self, dic):
        for i in dic.values():
            return(i)
    '''def timestamp_finding(self, dic):
        for i in dic.values():
            return(i)'''
```

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium.common.exceptions as selEx
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import datetime
import time
import io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests import get
from pattern.web import plaintext
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import random

#My modules
from modules.searcher import Searcher

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\op\\chromedriver.exe")

term_search = Searcher()
sites = term_search.search_sites
phones = term_search.phones
sites_found = ["theverge.com", "androidcentral.com", "macrumors.com"]

phone_index = 0
site_index = 0
count = 0
keep_going = True
current_site_url = 0
given_site_in_list_index = 0


while(keep_going):


    driver.get('https://www.Google.com')

    search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search.send_keys( sites[site_index] + " " + phones[phone_index] +   " review" )
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(4)
    my_search_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='rc']")

    sites_list = []

    for link in my_search_list:
        print("this is curernt site url ", current_site_url)
        if sites_found[current_site_url] in link.text:
            sites_list.append(link)

    go = True     
    while (go):
        print("this is len list ", len(sites_list))
        print("this is index ", given_site_in_list_index)
        time.sleep(4)
        if (given_site_in_list_index > len(sites_list)):
            break
        sites_list[given_site_in_list_index].click()
        time.sleep(4)
        go = False        
        given_site_in_list_index +=1



    #driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(phones[phone_index]).click()
    if(given_site_in_list_index == len(sites_list) or given_site_in_list_index > len(sites_list)):
        count +=1
        current_site_url +=1
        given_site_in_list_index = 0
        print("WE ARE INSIDE THE FIRST IF")
        driver.close()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\op\\chromedriver.exe")

        site_index +=1
        count = 0
        if(site_index == len(sites)):
            phone_index +=1
            site_index = 0
            current_site_url = 0
        elif(phone_index == len(phones)):
            keep_going = False
driver.close()
print("WE ARE AT THE BOTTOM")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\op\\chromedriver.exe")
```